# Android - location service not running in background, only when connected to the computer

Tags: java, android, service, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have created a service that has a LocationListener.
In the Fragment i have a BroadcastReceiver that successfully receives location from the Service. Everything works fine when the phone is connected to my computer and I have pressed "run" (not debug mode). I receive location continuously when the screen on my phone is turned off as I can see in the "Run" console in Android Studio.

However when i disconnect my phone from the computer and turn the screen off, I stoped receiving location updates. Or I got only one or two location updates before it stoped. Then when turning the screen on again the Service starts sending location updates.

I have tried using a WakeLock on the Fragment and the Service, but it dosent seem to have any effect.

Can someone help me please!?... :,(

In my Service I set a ArrayList->String in putExtra() that contains a Latitude and a TimeStamp so that I can see if the locationlistener did update location when screen is locked. And in the Fragment I display the results in the view so that I can manually debug.

Here is my Service code:

```
public class GpsService extends Service {

private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Intent mIntent;

private ArrayList<String> latTimeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    mIntent = new Intent("location_update");

    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            mIntent.putExtra("Latitude", location.getLatitude());
            mIntent.putExtra("Longitude", location.getLongitude());

            if(latTimeArrayList.size() < 10){

                latTimeArrayList.add(location.getLatitude() + " -> " + new Date());

            }else if(latTimeArrayList.size() == 10){
                mIntent.putExtra("latTimeArray", latTimeArrayList);
            }
            sendBroadcast(mIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    //noinspection MissingPermission
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 0, listener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0, listener);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationManager != null){
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

}

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
ArrayList<String> aString = new ArrayList<>();
private String mmtext = "";
TextView debugtext = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.hasCompletedTrack);
int doagain = 0;
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try{
                    if (doagain == 0){
                        aString = (ArrayList<String>)intent.getExtras().get("latTimeArray");
                        if(aString != null || aString.size() != 0){

                            for (int i =0; i< aString.size(); i++){
                                mmtext += aString.get(i) + "\n";
                            }
                            doagain = 1;
                            debugtext.setText(mmtext);
                        }
                    }


                }catch(NullPointerException e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

I had to turn off **PoweSaving mode** on my Samsung Galaxy S6 edge.

Also, in my `broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {`

that's in my Fragment, I did some position calculations for every location update that I got from my Service with a `Intent getExtra()` (this is not in the code I posted). However onReceive() only gets triggered when the screen is on(not locked). Therefore my calculations in the fragment were never triggered, only when the screen was on it triggered the calculation methods.

My solution to this was to handle all the calculations directly in my service.